# Using SharePoint 2013 TokenHelper class when there is no HttpContext.Current

Tags: 2013, office-365, sharepoint-addin, oauth

SharePoint 2013 Apps in Visual Studio have a TokenHelper class that simplifies using OAuth to connect to a SharePoint 2013 ClientContext.  I am using this class to remotely connect to a SharePoint 2013 (on Office 365).

I can use the TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAuthorizationCode method to get the ClientContext with the OAuth authorization code when running in a web application that has an HttpContext.Current.  However, if I use this same code in a console application or other context where there is no HttpContext.Current, the remote SharePoint 2013 server returns (400) Bad Request.

I've narrowed the issue down to the Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue() method.  When there is an HttpContext, it works, but without it gets the (400) Bad Request error.

I have tried using the Moq framework to fake an HttpContext, but that doesn't work either.

The failure occurs in the TokenHelper.GetAccessToken method here:

```
OAuth2S2SClient client = new OAuth2S2SClient();
OAuth2AccessTokenResponse oauth2Response;
try
{
    oauth2Response =
        client.Issue(AcsMetadataParser.GetStsUrl(realm), oauth2Request) as OAuth2AccessTokenResponse;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry if I don't understand your requirement correctly. So you are trying to connect to a SharePoint Online (Office 365) site from a console application?

Comment: Perhaps this post of mine might be helpful? http://vrdmn.blogspot.in/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html

Comment: Yes, similar to what you accomplish with your post.  However, rather than using the username/password each time, I am using an OAuth token that the user already configured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out what I was doing wrong:

1) The Authorization Code returned when creating the OAuth connection is only good for that browser session.  Thus why I couldn't reuse that authorization code later in back end services or in new browser sessions.

2) On the redirect page, I used the Authorization Code returned to create a new Access Token.  From the Access Token I could retrieve the Refresh Token.

3) The Refresh Token is what I can store and reuse later to create client contexts from back end code or new browser sessions.

So, in a nutshell, to reuse the OAuth token, you have to use the Refresh Token, not the Authorization Code.